# Why does Outlook keep moving emails into a custom "Junk" folder?

Tags: windows-8.1, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

I am using Office 365 and Outlook 2013 on Windows 8.1 for emails. There is one particular sender tom.dymoke@some-corp.com whose email keep going into a folder called Junk. This is not the normal Junk Email folder, this is a separate folder that I do not know come from where.

I have deleted this Junk folder but when I receive email from tom.dymoke@some-corp.com, the Junk folder is recreated and Tom's email goes into the folder.

I have also checked the Junk Email Options, Rules and Alerts, Automatically Move Messages and the Rule settings on Office 365. None of them have any rules set at all. I have also tried `outlook.exe /cleanrules` Where else can I look?

I don't think this is due to anti-spam mechanism, because I can rename the folder, move the folder to another folder, move it into delete items (delete the folder) etc. The incoming email will still always find its way into the folder. If I manually move the email back into inbox, for some reason after a minute the email will return to the Junk folder again.

Using the "Delivery Report" feature in Outlook/O365 Portal, it does not show any spam, filtering or rule actions, it merely says the email is delivered successfully.

So, why does this happen and how can I make it stop?

Message Header:

```
Received: from SINPR06MB332.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.141.110.18) by
 HKXPR06MB326.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.141.133.16) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (TLS) id 15.0.1044.10 via Mailbox Transport; Mon, 13 Oct 2014 07:53:17
 +0000
Received: from SIXPR06CA0032.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com (25.160.171.150) by
 SINPR06MB332.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com (10.141.110.18) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (TLS) id 15.0.1039.15; Mon, 13 Oct 2014 07:53:09 +0000
Received: from AM1FFO11FD031.protection.gbl (2a01:111:f400:7e00::134) by
 SIXPR06CA0032.outlook.office365.com (2a01:111:e400:b400::22) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server (TLS) id 15.0.1049.19 via Frontend Transport; Mon, 13 Oct 2014
 07:53:09 +0000
Received: from emea01-db3-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (157.55.234.100)
 by AM1FFO11FD031.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.174.64.220) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server (TLS) id 15.0.1039.16 via Frontend Transport; Mon, 13 Oct 2014
 07:53:07 +0000
Received: from DB3PR05MB553.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com (10.141.3.141) by
 DB3PR05MB556.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com (10.141.3.27) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (TLS) id 15.0.1049.19; Mon, 13 Oct 2014 07:51:43 +0000
Received: from DB3PR05MB553.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com ([10.141.3.141]) by
 DB3PR05MB553.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com ([10.141.3.141]) with mapi id
 15.00.1049.012; Mon, 13 Oct 2014 07:51:43 +0000
From: Tom Dymoke <Tom.Dymoke@some-corp.com>
To: Abigail Teh <abigail.teh@sister-corp.com>
CC: Serene Lee <serene.lee@sister-corp.com>
Subject: RE: Sister Corp OTL Report September WK4
Thread-Topic: Sister Corp OTL Report September WK4
Thread-Index: Ac/mjOvLA9JV6ns5TRumdK4Tl+HA1gALYi+g
Date: Mon, 13 Oct 2014 07:51:43 +0000
Message-ID: <f66b5e7500ae4b68aa260b87af7d83fa@DB3PR05MB553.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com>
References: <a10e15cbc4224f88839323ec8f7d0533@HK2PR06MB0433.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com>
In-Reply-To: <a10e15cbc4224f88839323ec8f7d0533@HK2PR06MB0433.apcprd06.prod.outlook.com>
Accept-Language: en-GB, en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
x-ms-exchange-transport-fromentityheader: Hosted
x-originating-ip: [123.213.132.231]
x-microsoft-antispam: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:DB3PR05MB556;UriScan:;
x-exchange-antispam-report-test: UriScan:;UriScan:;
x-forefront-prvs: 03630A6A4A
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report-Untrusted: SFV:NSPM;SFS:(10009020)(199003)(189002)(86362001)(31966008)(17760045003)(16236675004)(74316001)(108616004)(19580405001)(21056001)(97736003)(20776003)(92566001)(19580395003)(105586002)(18206015026)(33646002)(19617315012)(19627595001)(15202345003)(76576001)(106356001)(110136001)(107046002)(95666004)(66066001)(76482002)(85852003)(50986999)(99936001)(54356999)(85306004)(64706001)(87936001)(120916001)(19618635001)(19300405004)(4396001)(2656002)(99396003)(101416001)(19625215002)(122556002)(46102003)(80022003)(76176999)(40100003)(24736002);DIR:OUT;SFP:1101;SCL:1;SRVR:DB3PR05MB556;H:DB3PR05MB553.eurprd05.prod.outlook.com;FPR:;MLV:sfv;PTR:InfoNoRecords;A:1;MX:1;LANG:en;
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="_006_f66b5e7500ae4b68aa260b87af7d83faDB3PR05MB553eurprd05pro_"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Return-Path: Tom.Dymoke@some-corp.com
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: CIP:157.55.234.100;CTRY:US;IPV:NLI;IPV:NLI;EFV:NLI;SFV:SFE;SFS:;DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:0;SRVR:SINPR06MB332;H:emea01-db3-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com;FPR:;LANG:en;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: e24aa4b7-1ee1-493c-ba58-08d1b4d1df19
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:SINPR06MB332;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Service: 1.0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: AM1FFO11FD031.protection.gbl
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
```

Comment: 1) Have you tried adding this person to your safe sender list? Does that change where the e-mail goes? 2) Have you tried adding them to your contacts, then checking on the trust anyone in your contacts? 3) Is the e-mail being sent to your Office 365 account e-mail and then to Outlook 2013?

Comment: Yes to all. Still not working.

Comment: If you open the email itself you can see the message headers I think under email options. It is hidden sort of... But it will tell you the path it took to get to your inbox. If you can copy and paste that into your question, that will help.

Comment: Was the email ever quarantined?

Comment: I made a small edit. If info is missing, people will ask you anyway, and then you can just [edit] that info into the post. Otherwise you'll be asking for [your attempted solution rather than the issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Is your company using exchange server? Is the "Junk" folder getting created on your exchange account as well?

Comment: It's Office365. I have checked Office365 and I do not have any server-side settings that moves emails to any folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds an awful lot like something I've just been dealing with.
It's caused by a Samsung Galaxy phone/tablet device being setup to access that mailbox.
The Galaxy device creates the "Junk" folder (as opposed to the usual Outlook/Exchange mailbox one called "Junk E-Mail").
If you delete the Galaxy "Junk" folder, it will be recreated. If you rename it, messages will still end up there.
In order to stop this, you need to open the email app on the phone, press the ***Menu*** button and go to ***Settings*** ... ***Spam Addresses***. Remove the erroneously marked addresses from the spam list.
That's how it works on my phone, but I have found other instructions which suggest you need to go to ***Settings***... ***General Settings***... ***Spam Addresses*** - so perhaps my email app is a slightly different version to the one used by the author of [these other instructions](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/moves-email-junk-folder/).

Comment: This sounds promising! I will go check and hopefully return to mark as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Since the SCL value is 0, it does not [bypass spam filtering](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn798345(v=exchg.150).aspx).

```
0-4 – When you set the SCL to one of these values, 
the message will be passed along to the content filter 
for additional processing.
```

The default action when content is filtered (at the server level) is to [move it to the junk email folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200684(v=exchg.150).aspx).

The last bit about junk folder vs junk e-mail folder is a mystery. Some ideas:

- Perhaps the email admin, assigned eligible email to move to junk instead of junk e-mail folder.
- The other possibility is that you have an outlook add-in such as anti-virus that is performing [unwanted content filtering](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/how-to-disable-outlooks-junk-email-filter/).

Comment: The folder in question is not the Outlook Junk Email folder, it is a regular folder named Junk. I can rename it to anything too. So I don't think it is the native Automatic Junk Filtering. What else can it be?

Comment: It also cannot be at the server level because only 1 user has this problem when the email is CC-ed to many recipients on the same domain/server. I think it should be client issue.

Comment: What addins does the outlook client have? Are there any antivirus, anti malware running on the computer that might interact with outlook emails?