# Junk Email in Outlook still going to Junk folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, spam-prevention

I have 3 users experiencing the following problem.
I set up their email accounts, 2 addresses both using the same pst file in Outlook 2010.
On initial set up, I set Junk Email settings to No Automatic Filtering.
This works for some users, where no email goes to the Junk folder.
However for these 3 users it is not working.
Occasionally I have to run their message rules on the mail in Junk, in order for them to find their valid emails.
Is there anyway to remove the Junk folder completely?
We are not making use of an Exchange server, so some of the threads I have read regarding this, do not apply

Comment: Is it a plug-in from their internet security software which is making the difference?

Comment: No plug-ins are install, all set ups are plain vanilla

Comment: OK. I was trying to think of something to explain why some of the installations behave differently. Nothing else comes to mind, I'm afraid.

Comment: Are your users using Samsung phones to access their mailboxes? I answered a similar issue here: http://superuser.com/questions/822383/why-does-outlook-keep-moving-emails-into-a-custom-junk-folder/826062#826062 - although that was Exchange, the Samsung mail client would have the same effect against any IMAP mailbox.

Comment: No, they're only accessing the email via the pc email client, Outlook 2010. They don't access their mail via the web portal either, so that shouldn't be causing this. I have tried adding certain domains to the safe senders list, but this hasn't worked yet

Comment: I found a blog entry that sounded like the problem experienced by my users. 
So far this has proven to be the solution http://sherylcanter.com/wordpress/2012/12/how-to-turn-off-the-junk-e-mail-filter-in-outlook-2010/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer so far:
http://sherylcanter.com/wordpress/2012/12/how-to-turn-off-the-junk-e-mail-filter-in-outlook-2010/
No more mail is filtering into the Junk Email folder